# Magento 2 not working on Samsung Internet

Tags: checkout, javascript

Currently experiencing an issue with Magento 2 on the Samsung Internet browser. This occurs on most pages, though it's more prominent (and a bigger problem) on the checkout.

The checkout takes roughly 40 seconds to load. There are multiple console logs stating `[Violation] 'load' handler took (X)ms`, with `(X)` being around 500-700ms. I have tested this with blank Magento 2 installations and it seems to be consistent.

This doesn't seem to affect larger Magento sites such as Nike.

Is there anything that you could recommend?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find a fix for this? Cart and search do not open on homepage (but work fine in product pages) on samsung browser